# Use one variable to create another using while loop

Tags: sql, loops, while-loop

Trying to create a list of customers (for further analysis) that have attended specific concerts.  There will be a maximum of 5 parameters in my SP (one for each concert).  Note that there may be less than 5, but at least 1.  Before looking at sales, I want to ensure that the concert codes (parameters) are legit and said concert codes actually reside in a t_perf table.  So far, I have `@perfcode1` through `@perfcode5` created as `char(8)` and are set to `null`.

While this will check each parameter to make sure it exists in the `t_perf` table, I'd like to use a while loop that creates `@perfcode1` through `5`, rather than doing this 5 times.

```
if @perfcode1 is not null
    if @perfcode1 not in (select perf_code from T_PERF where perf_code = @perfcode1)
    begin  
        print @perfcode1 + 'is invalid'
        return
    end
```

I'd like to use one variable to create another variable and then see if the `perf_code` is valid.  Something like `@perfcode@cnt` which would create `@perfcode1`, then `@perfcode2`, then `@perfcode3` and so on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could pass in a comma-separated list as the variable; splitting up that list will depend on what DB you're using.

Comment: It is not necessary to loop through each parameter.  Are you saying you don't know for sure how many parameters there will be yet?

Comment: You could insert your variables into a temp table and then join on that and check that all the rows are still there.  Other than that, writing five `if not exists` statements doesn't seem over the top to me.  If you want, you could write a function that checks for existence, and then just call that for each variable.

Comment: The only way to do this in a loop is to combine your 5 different parameter objects into a single "set" object.  How that is accomplished depends on what specific type of SQL database you are using.  As a previous comment says, a delimited string would work.  In SQL Server 2008 you could use "[table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489(v=sql.105).aspx)"  You should update your question with the specific database engine you are using.

Comment: Thanks for all of the replies.  I'm using SQL 2008 R2 still.  Still learning SQL and have a long way to go.  In any given week, there will be a max of 5 concerts, usually less.  I've allowed for 5 in my SP and set them all to null if they aren't used, so I don't get any errors when I run it.  I don't have to run this through a loop but was hoping to learn something new.  Any suggestions on code?